# C++ request for member ‘’ in ‘’, which is of non-class type ‘’

Tags: c++

I have written a simple C++ program which is as follows-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
    double length, breadth;

public:
    Rectangle(void);        // constructor overloading
    Rectangle(double, double);  // constructor of class
    // void set_values(double l, double b);
    double area(void);
};  // can provide an object name here


// default constructor of class 'Rectangle'-
Rectangle::Rectangle(void)
{
    length = 5;
    breadth = 5;
}


// constructor of class 'Rectangle'-
Rectangle::Rectangle(double l, double b)
{
    length = l;
    breadth = b;
}


/*
void Rectangle::set_values(double l, double b)
{
    length = l;
    breadth = b;
}
*/


double Rectangle::area(void)
{
    return length * breadth;
}


int main()
{
    /*
    Rectangle r;
    r.set_values(12, 3.4);
    */

    Rectangle r(12, 3.4);
    Rectangle s();

    cout<<"Area = "<<r.area()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area = "<<s.area()<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error-

```
Classes_Example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Classes_Example.cpp:61:21: error: request for member ‘area’ in ‘s’, which is of non-class type ‘Rectangle()’
  cout<<"Area = "<<s.area()<<endl;
```

I am using g++ (GCC) 7.2.0

Thanks!

Comment: `Rectangle s();` is a function declaration.

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). We really need a canonical Q&A entry for this. I'm surprised I can't find one.

Comment: `Rectangle s();` declares a function named `s` that takes no arguments and returns a `Rectangle`. This is known as the most vexing parse in C++. Change it to `Rectangle s;` or `Rectangle s{};`.

Comment: @Cornstalks, I was thinking of the same thing.

Comment: You should always use [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). No problems with most vexing parse is just one of its benefits.

Comment: @Cornstalks Most Vexing Parse refers to the case when there are also attempted arguments, e.g. `T f( U(x) );`. I call this one the "slightly vexing parse"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Rectangle s();
```

is a function declaration rather than variable. In c++ anything that can be parsed as a function declaration takes that parsing over the variable alternative. Removing the () would make it a variable.